# cannot find symbol - variable UP

Tags: java

I need to make a box which had 4 buttons UP, DOWN, RIGHT and LEFT, in the centre needs to be writing so whenever i click one of the buttons its says "Going Right!" etc. It keeps saying cannot find symbol - variable UP. what do i do?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class BorderLayoutFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    private JButton[] buttons; 
    private static final String[] names = { "UP", "DOWN", "RIGHT", "LEFT", };
    private BorderLayout layout;


    public BorderLayoutFrame()
    {
        super ("BorderLayout Demo");

        layout = new BorderLayout( 5, 5); 
        setLayout( layout );
        buttons = new JButton[ names.length ];

        for ( int count = 0; count < names.length; count++ )
        {
            buttons[ count ] = new JButton( names[ count ] ); 
            buttons[ count ].addActionListener( this );
        }

        add( buttons[ 0 ], BorderLayout.UP ); 
        add( buttons[ 1 ], BorderLayout.DOWN );
        add( buttons[ 2 ], BorderLayout.RIGHT );
        add( buttons[ 3 ], BorderLayout.LEFT );
    }

    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
    {
        for ( JButton button  : buttons )
        {
            if ( event.getSource() == button)
               button.setVisible( false );

               button.setVisible( true );
            }
            layout. layoutContainer( getContentPane() );

}

}
```

Comment: Why do you think `BorderLayout` has fields called `UP`, `DOWN`, etc.?

Comment: i dont know, could you help me please?

Comment: @Aneeqa Please learn to [read the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) where you find that those fields obviously do not exist.

Comment: I understand that now, could you just explain to me how I can get the centre writing to say "Going North!" when i click the north button?

Answer (score 0):

You should use location constants from BorderLayout class. For example 
BorderLayout.CENTER BorderLayout.NORTH BorderLayout.SOUTH

```
add( buttons[ 0 ], BorderLayout.NORTH ); 
add( buttons[ 1 ], BorderLayout.SOUTH);
add( buttons[ 2 ], BorderLayout.EAST);
add( buttons[ 3 ], BorderLayout.WEST );
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you are using some non-existent fields:

```
BorderLayout.UP
BorderLayout.DOWN
BorderLayout.LEFT
BorderLayout.RIGHT
```

These should be, respectively:

```
BorderLayout.NORTH
BorderLayout.SOUTH
BorderLayout.EAST
BorderLayout.WEST
```

Please see the BorderLayout documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html). It would be a good idea to check it first next time, prior to asking a question.

Comment: Thank you. could you explain to me how I can get the centre writing to say "Going North!" when i click the north button?

Comment: @Aneeqa Maybe [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) Oracle tutorial on using BorderLayout can help you.